# Javascript if statement ampersand replace with &#038 in wordpress

Tags: javascript, wordpress, if-statement

I have a wordpress plugin and recently I am facing a problem with "&&"(ampersand) sibmble in javascript.
It (`&&`) replace with `&#038;&#038;`

**My Code :**

```
if(typeof jQuery(this).data("fieldtype") != "undefined" 
            && jQuery(this).data("fieldtype") === "lookup") {
    // action
}
```

Converted Code :

```
if(typeof jQuery(this).data("fieldtype") != "undefined" 
                &#038;&#038; jQuery(this).data("fieldtype") === "lookup") {
       // action 
}
```

I found some solution like `encodeURIComponent`, `srt_replace` but I can not use them in if/else statement.

Can you please tell what's the reason to convert ampersand(&) and how can I fix.

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found in my debugging, that the issue was created for javascript code in PHP file. I move the javascript code to a .js file and the issue is fixed for me.